# How reliable is identification via DNA matching?

Tags: genetics, criminology

For example, how did they identify Osama bin Ladin? How can they identify with such confidence a DNA match?

How can you compare DNA against a sister and determine that it is indeed Osama bin Ladin?

The man could have been a relative, not a perfect match.

Comment: How many siblings of OBL's sister are fighting with Al Qaeda in Pakistan? Also, please use proper grammar in your questions: end questions with a question mark, use capitals for "Osama" and "Ladin", and consider using a comma after "relative".

Comment: DNA matching refers to a broad series of technologies. Could you point to a source that describe the way Osama bin Ladin was supposedly identified?

Comment: This could all have been a staged show. The dead man could have been a cousin.

Comment: @Mathiax:True. But in that case, Osama just has to appear on camera to prove them wrong. And due to the large amount of negative sentiment that would be generated atowards the president if Osama was alive, I am sure Obama made sure of the facts before releasing the details.

Comment: @apoorv020 my point it is only highly probable that the man is Osama. To be 100% sure, they would need to compare the DNA against an original sample of Osama himself; in which case when and how did they collect it. He is from a big family, many could look like him and also have a close enough DNA profile. And even if it was him, nothing is to stop another smart cazy nut job  from  pretending to be him.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about DNA, but it answers your question about whether bin Laden was killed: Al Qaeda is also stating that [bin Laden was killed](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/2011/05/07/2011-05-07_al_qaeda_warns_of_vengeance_against_united_states_as_it_confirms_death_of_bin_la.html). While I don't regard Al Qaeda as a particularly trustworthy organization, it makes claims that he's alive and un-captured less plausible.

Comment: I think the best point about Osama's death was made by David Leppik on [Bruce Schneier's blog](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/05/extreme_authent.html): *"Ultimately, I think the only authentication that matters is this: Al Qaeda hasn't claimed that he's still alive. If he were still breathing, he would have issued a press release."*

Comment: Tapes and other information was collected from the compound. This is what confirmed the death. DNA alone cannot. http://abcnews.go.com/Blotter/osama-bin-laden-tapes-show-pathetic-side-al/story?id=13559652

Comment: Some people confuse identity with a method of identification. To compare Osama bin Ladin with a DNA sample, you have to have a DNA sample, of which you can be sure, it is authentic. Maybe the man is not the brother of the daughter of his mother, but he might still be the searched terrorist. And if he is, this is important, not his DNA or a passport.

Answer (score 4):

From [NewScientist](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20439-osama-bin-laden-how-dna-identified-his-body.html):

> **Using DNA from many half-siblings
>   could produce a DNA match of greater
>   than 90 per cent confidence, but it
>   would be difficult to get as high as
>   99.9 per cent without a closer relative** says [Rhonda Roby](http://www.hsc.unt.edu/departments/Forensics/faculty.cfm), a forensic
>   geneticist at the University of North
>   Texas Health Science Center, Fort
>   Worth.
>
> Roby, who led the team using DNA
>   evidence to identify the remains of
>   people killed in the 9/11 attacks in
>   2001, says that the statistical
>   analysis based on **DNA from
>   half-siblings is more complex and less
>   reliable than analysis based on DNA
>   from a closer relative like a parent
>   or child.**

There are [reports](http://www.reuters.com/article/2011/05/02/us-obama-binladen-son-idUSTRE7410T520110502) that one of bin Laden's sons was also killed in the raid.

> Roby says **DNA from a son and several
>   half-siblings could confirm Osama's
>   identity with 99.9 per cent accuracy.**
>
> If, however, the government was able
>   to obtain **DNA from bin Laden's body,
>   his son and also that son's biological
>   mother** – who might have been at the
>   compound during the raid, it **could
>   perform DNA profiling with a "full
>   paternity trio", assuring 99.9 per
>   cent accuracy**, Roby says.

---

According to [ABC](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/Wellness/osama-bin-laden-relatives-dna-matching-technique-reliable/story?id=13510123):

> **DNA collected from bin Laden's body
>   Sunday was compared to DNA from
>   multiple relatives**, a U.S.
>   intelligence official told ABC News.
>
> **The U.S. is believed to have collected
>   DNA samples from bin Laden family
>   members in the years since the 9/11
>   attacks** that triggered the U.S.-led
>   invasion of Afghanistan.

---

The [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/03/science/03dna.html?_r=1&partner=rss&emc=rss) says the same:

> **Officials said they collected multiple
>   DNA samples from Bin Laden’s relatives
>   in the years since the Sept. 11
>   attacks.**
>
> Bin Laden did not have any full siblings. He did have more than 50 half-siblings, some of whom have close ties to the United States and had long ago distanced themselves from him.

---

**Christie Wilcox** explains in a [Scientific American article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/blog/post.cfm?id=how-do-you-id-a-dead-osama-anyway-2011-05-02) how the get a **DNA fingerprint** and that nowadays it takes only a few hours.

Comment: Again don't see how this analysis makes it 99.9% conclusive. The premise is that the son is Osams son. But how did they Id the Son. The killed son, could have just been the son of the man killed. The argument is like a house of cards based on circular dependecies.

Comment: @mathaix - AFAIK it's not yet know what family member(s) was/were used for the DNA match. But apparently OBL had [more than 20 children](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/asiapcf/05/05/osama.many.wives/index.html?iref=NS1). Plus, DNA wasn't the only method used to [identify him](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=how-biometrics-helped-to-identify-master-terrorist).

Comment: This implies, that you can confirm the identity of the killed son, and that the father of both sons is identical. AFAIK, a lot of social fathers aren't genetic fathers.